# Background-color transition CSS on Safari not working well

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, background-color

My problem is very visual, as you can see in the image. Each slide match with a background-color applied to the body (.active-slide-x is a class of the body changing with the current slide). We begin with black and finish by white background with different nuances of grey between. In Javascript, a red round move and its size change depending on the slide.

But on Safari, the background change only on the move of the red round. Even the navigation in red has some problems (the white background is not normal).

My CSS code:

```
body {
  transition: background-color 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 500ms ease;
  background-color: #000;
 }

.active-slide-1{background-color: white;}
.active-slide-2{background-color: #f4f4f2;}
.active-slide-3{background-color: #d4d3d1;}
.active-slide-4{background-color: #a5a29b;}
.active-slide-5{background-color: #76716c;}
.active-slide-6{background-color: #4c4843;}
.active-slide-7{background-color: #262321;}
.active-slide-8{background-color: black;}
```

Safari apply the webkit transition but not very good. It's the same on iPhone and iPad.

[image: safari]

Sorry for my english, I'm french but hope to find a solution with you !

Comment: could you either add your html or create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net ?